# How to store the value of text box in local storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save the username which is in text box to later retrieve it on another web page using javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index1.html">
username:<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname">
password:<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
login:<input type="submit" name="login" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
localStorage.setItem('username','myusername');
```

Now get the stored key

```
localStorage.getItem('username') //myusername
```

Comment: i want the value of text box username in place of myusername

Comment: `localStorage.
setItem
('username',document.getElementById('uname').value)`

Answer (score 0):

it is possible using html5.We can store some values in localstorage in HTML5

[see here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If your not using html5, You could store it in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The context between page reloads is typically lost for JavaScript, you might want to consider using JQuery to provide an application that looks like it is running on multiple pages, but is in fact just one page with transitions.

Your other option is to store the value in a cookie, or in a local storage web database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You have a button. Just call the method to store the values in the button **`click`** event.

```
  $(function () {

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        alert(name);
        localStorage.setItem('username',name);
    });
});
```

Fiddled Example [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/hr3xQ/1/).

Local Storage API and a playground to try it yourself, [**`HTML5`**](http://playground.html5rocks.com/#localstorage).

The output, you will be able to see while you ***inspect element*** as a pair of **Key** and **Value**. Under resources tab, In case, you use **`firebug`**.

## EDIT

I have also updated the sample fiddle.